# How to assign a fixed IP (for whitelisting purpose) to a group of EC2 that has ASG configured?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, static-ip-address

I have a group of EC2 worker instances (with ASG configured and within a VPC) that runs hourly to pull data from third-party API.

The issue i am facing now is the third-party API is implementing whitelisting of IP.

How can i provide static IPs for the third-party API to whitelist?

Elastic IP will not be useful in this scenario because of the ASG configured (different IP every time new instances spin up).

Comment: Configure ASG in private subnet and use [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

Comment: This works. thank you for your answer @DusanBajic

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to attach IP from given range of IP's by `UserData` script.

For this you need:

```
$ sudo apt install -y python-pip
$ sudo pip install aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip --valid-ips 164.543.543.234
```

**You should replace this IP in `--valid-ips` option.**

**You can add here multiple IP's, but you have to own them - so `Elastic IP` is great idea here**